# Giving JPanel Two BorderLayout Assignments

Tags: jpanel

I want to set a JPanel to have two BorderLayout assignments:

panel.add(panel1, BorderLayout.LINE_END, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

How do I do this without breaking the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... I solved it by adding multiple JPanels on top of eachother.